# Webpack css-loader does not consider localIdentName

Tags: reactjs, webpack, css-loader

I am using the css-loader as Webpack plugin to transform my css class name but the localIndentName option has no effect.

Here's my webpack configuration concerning the css-loader:

```
{
    test: /(\.css|\.scss|\.sass)$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: true,
          module: true,
          localIndentName:'[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:5]'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

The class of my html elements are being transformed to hash value only:

```
<div class="_3FKNgBgNuQfnCln2xIoxoO">
   <div class="_3qj_5lUx_x_cKsHgbKmTIq"></div>
</div>
```

I am using the following versions:

- node: 8.11.1
- npm: 6.0.1
- webpack: 4.8.3
- css-loader: 0.28.11

Does someone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: hi there how to transform the html into something like that? I've followed ur config its only transform the classname on .css but the html still using normal name @DavidH

Answer (score 2):

> but the localIndentName option has no effect

Was dealing with same issue. 
Assuming there is the typo in some of the tutorials...

The options property must be **localIdentName** not *localIndentName*.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this way,

```
 modules: true,
 modules: {
       localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
           }
```

instead of

```
module: true,
      localIndentName:'[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:5]'
```